# Twitter Integration

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating a MVC 5 application in Visual Studio 2013 Preview. I want to integrate Twitter in my MVC application. I have used Twitter.Helper from Package Manager. But when my application runs on the browser nothing happen. Here is my code in Index.cshtml file:

```
<div class="span4">
    <h2>My Profile</h2>
    @TwitterGoodies.Profile("Sandeep Sharma")
</div>
```

Comment: What kind of integration? You want to let them log in via Twitter?

Comment: @artplastika i want to show my profile in the browser

Comment: @artplastika I followed http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2011/05/24/integrating-twitter-with-your-asp.net-mvc-3-and-razor-web.aspx
to create twitter integration, but i am not getting my profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the browser console, you will see errors:

```
TWITTER WIDGET: The Twitter API v1.0 is deprecated, and this widget has ceased functioning. widget.js:1
TWITTER WIDGET: You can replace it with a new, upgraded widget from <https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new/user?screen_name=ranganh> widget.js:1
TWITTER WIDGET: For more information on alternative Twitter tools, see <https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-for-websites> widget.js:1
```

This means Twitter.Helper use old and deprecated Twitter API and should be modified to conform API changes. You could make it manually in file: `MvcApplicationProject\App_Code\TwitterGoodies.cshtml`

Comment: I am getting this error TWTR is not defined. What should I do?

Comment: The answer is: this library won't work because it uses outdated API.